# lower skill level than proficiency

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I am looking for a noun which describes a lower level of skill than proficiency, a synonym for intermediate. A word that would fit in this context:

conversational .... in Greek

I am trying to say that I speak the language on an intermediate level

Any ideas?

Comment: *intermediate*.  But it might be more informative to specify the levels for reading, writing, listening/understanding, and speaking. They are typically not the same.

Answer (score 4):

Try **conversant**, it literally means being able to hold a conversation (in a foreign language).  The usage would be "I am **conversant** in Greek."

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conversant

Answer (score 0):

Greenhorn / Veteran

Feel free for Reference

http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_Levels

Comment: cite veteran and greenhorn in a reputable American English dictionary too.

Comment: @ibf I had to reject an edit suggested by you, because it seems that the OP is proposing "Call of duty" as a solution. The answers he is suggesting are two: "greenhorn" and "veteran". Call of duty is the name of the Wiki page *link*

Comment: Rohit Tripathi, I think you have misunderstood the question being asked, the poster wants a noun that is suitable for a speaker of a foreign at an intermediate level, for example, "She is a/an ____  Arab speaker" See Chris's suggested answer above.